# How to hide html element in option when selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using ant design and its select component. My code is:

```
<Select>
  <Option>
    <Text>Some title</Text> <Text>This is the text i want to hide when option is selected</Text>
  </Option>
</Select>
```

I need to hide the second text element when an option is selected, is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why don't you use a state and conditional rendering on the element you want to hide?

Comment: @programandoconro because then it would hide it when options list is open(when an option is selected)

Comment: What is Option? it looks not an antd element.

Comment: But you are saying `I need to hide the second text element when an option is selected`. Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: You can customize the selected option text by using antd Select `optionLabelProp` prop. Please follow this [Custom selection render](https://ant.design/components/select#select-demo-option-label-prop) example.